# JSF throws class does not have the property for DynamicEntity

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, eclipselink

I want to use a [DynamicEntity](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/dynamic/DynamicEntity.html) as a managed bean providing properties for my xhtml form.

When I use the above as backing bean for my xhtml page, I got the following exception:

```
The class 'com.invoice.Invoic' does not have the property 'sellerAddress'.
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:200)
com.tsystems.odx.idm.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:231)
org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:38)
org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:263)
org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188)
com.tsystems.odx.idm.authentication.web.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter
```

I put a debug breakpoint and looked into my DynamicEntity object, the sellerAddress object was there.

Here is a dummy example how I would like to use DynamicEntity as bean

```
package com.test.beans;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.DynamicJAXBContextFactory;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CustomerHandler {

    DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws JAXBException {
        InputStream xsdInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customer.xsd");
        jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null,
                null);
    }

    @Produces
    @Named("Customer")
    public DynamicEntity createCustomer() {
        DynamicEntity customer = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.example.Customer");
        customer.set("name", "Jane Doe");
        DynamicEntity address = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("org.example.Address");
        address.set("street", "1 Any Street").set("city", "Any Town");
        customer.set("address", address);
        return customer;
    }

    public void save()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The customer.xsd file is in src/main/resources

```
<xsd:schema 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns="http://www.example.org" 
   targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xsd:complexType name="address">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:element name="customer">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="address" type="address" minOccurs="0"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And my test page is customer.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Welcome to Customer Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{Customer.name}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{Customer.address.street}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{customerHandler.save()}" />
    </h:form>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elaborate on your use case. The reference you made is an interface. How do you implement it, share your `Invoice` class? How do you use/reference it, share the way you access the property? Besides, the first line of your stack trace is rather self-documentary and gives you clues what could be wrong with your code.

Comment: @skuntsel I have posted a sample above.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [`DynamicEntity`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/dynamic/DynamicEntity.html) class shows us that it is an interface and nowhere states that this interface provides for good old POJO getters like `getSellerAddress()` that will return the desired property. As you're trying to manipulate the values as `#{Customer.name}` that is indeed not going to work, as there is no `getName()`/`setName()` method pair.

The methods exposed by the `DynamicEntity` interfaces are the following:

- `DynamicEntity#get(propertyName)` to retrieve the value and
- `DynamicEntity#set(propertyName, value)` to preset the value.

So there is clearly no way to use these methods to create a bilateral binding with a bean property in a standard JSF way.

---

You have the following choices to deal with your problem:

1. Switch to JPA and create real entities like `@Entity public class Customer` as your model. This is clearly the best way to go further and the best practice;
2. Create a placeholder/backing bean to a JSF form to keep the submitted values and create your dynamic entity in the action method for further manipulation. Be aware that you will miss all the points of JSF if you decide to follow this route;
3. Most probably the implementation of `DynamicEntity` (that is, the instance returned from the call to `DynamicJAXBContext#newDynamicEntity(String n)`) is backed by a `Map` implementation. Debug to see what that call returns and apply that information to your use case. In case it's backed by a map with a public getter/setter pair with the name `persistentMap` your EL will become `#{Customer.persistentMap['name']`. Be aware that this is a discouraged practice and an example of tight coupling and is possible in case there are accessors for the backed collection.

To sum it up, I'd highly recommended to switch to JPA to solve your use case.

Comment: 1. switch to JPA completely is not possible because of business requirements. 2. not feasible 3. not recommended way.  Can we use dynamic proxies, dont know JSF would work with that? Is there any other way, like extending the EL resolution mechanism for this special case?